# Asynchronous Request Within a ForEach in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, foreach, requestjs

I am new to node.js (and to request.js). I'd like to get the body of a website back from a specific url with different paths (in the example below http://www.example.com/path1, http://www.example.com/path2, etc.) and log this data in an object with a key/value mapping (siteData[path] below).

```
var request = require('request'),
    paths = ['path1','path2','path3'],
    siteData = {},
    pathLength = paths.length,
    pathIndex = 0;

paths.forEach((path) => {
    var url="http://www.example.com/"+path;
    request(url, function(error, response, html){
        if(!error){
            siteData[path] = response.body;
            pathIndex++;
            if(pathIndex===pathLength){
                someFunction(siteData);
            }
        }
});

function someFunction(data){
    //manipulate data
}
```

My questions are:

- The if statement (index === length) doesn't look like the right way to determine if the asynchronous requests are finished. How should I properly check if the requests are finished?
- When I execute the code above I get an error `(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 unpipe listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.` I tried chaining `request(url, function(...){}).setMaxListeners(100);` but that didn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like Promises are the right tool to get the job done here.  Instead of a callback, we'll create a new `Promise` object that will resolve when the job is done.  We can say "once you're done, do some more stuff" with the `.then` operator:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

rp('http://www.google.com')
  .then((htmlString) => {
    // Process html... 
  });
```

(if anything goes wrong, the promise *rejects* and goes straight to `.catch`)

```
someFunctionThatErrors('Yikes!')
  .then((data) => {
    // won't be called
  })
.catch((err) => {
  // Will be called, we handle the error here
});
```

We've got lots of async tasks to do, so just one promise won't work.  One option is to string them all together in series, like so:

```
rp('http://www.google.com')
  .then((htmlString) => rp('http://someOtherUrl.com'))
  .then((otherHtmlString) => {
    // and so forth...
```

But that loses some of the awesome of async - we can do all of these tasks in *parallel*.

```
var myRequests = [];
myRequests.push(rp('http://www.google.com').then(processStuff).catch(handleErr));
myRequests.push(rp('http://someOtherUrl.com').then(processStuff).catch(handleErr));
```

...boy does that look ugly.  There's a better way with all of this - [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (You're using arrow functions so I assume native `Promise` will work for you too).  It takes an array of promises and returns a promise that resolves when **all** of the array's promises have finished executing.  (If any of them error, it immediately rejects).  The `.then` function will be given an *array* representing the value each promise resolved to.

```
var myRequests = [];
myRequests.push(rp('http://www.google.com'));
myRequests.push(rp('http://someOtherUrl.com'));
Promise.all(myRequests)
  .then((arrayOfHtml) => {
    // arrayOfHtml[0] is the results from google,
    // arrayOfHtml[1] is the results from someOtherUrl
    // ...etc
    arrayOfHtml.forEach(processStuff);
  })
  .catch(/* handle error */);
```

Still, we have to manually call `.push` for every link we want to hit.  That won't do!  Let's pull a nifty trick using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which will iterate over our array, manipulating each value in turn and return a new array comprised of the new values:

```js
var arrayOfPromises = paths.map((path) => rp(`http://www.example.com/${path}`));
Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)
  .then((arrayOfHtml) => arrayOfHtml.forEach(processStuff))
  .catch(function (err) { console.log('agh!'); });
```

Much cleaner and easier error handling.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, you can't just use a forEach or any kind of loop when dealing with request module since it executes asynchronously and ends up with EventEmitter memory leak.

The way I solve this is by using a recursive function. You can refer on the code below:

```
var request = require('request'),
    paths = ['path1','path2','path3'],
    siteData = {};

function requestSiteData(paths) {
    if (paths.length) {
        var path = paths.shift();
        var url = "http://www.example.com/" + path;

        request(url, function(error, response, html) {
            if(!error) {
                siteData[path] = response.body;
            } //add else block if want to terminate when error occur

            //continue to process data even if error occur
            requestSiteData(paths); //call the same function
        });
    } else {
        someFunction(siteData); //all paths are requested
    }
}

function someFunction(data){
    //manipulate data
}

requestSiteData(paths); //start requesting data
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to asynchronous nature of `request` method in nodejs, you can not directly know their responses and act on realtime. You have wait for the callback to arrive and then only you can call the next `request` method.

Here in this case, you are calling all the `request` methods in `forEach` loop meaning they are getting called one by one without waiting for the previous responses.

I would suggest to use wonderful `async` library for this purpose as below -

```
 var async = require('aysnc');
 var request = require('request'),
 paths = ['path1','path2','path3'],
 siteData = {},
 pathLength = paths.length,
 pathIndex = 0,
 count = 0;

async.whilst(
  function () { return count < pathLength; },
  function (callback) {
    // do your request call here 
    var path = paths[pathLength];
    var url="http://www.example.com/"+path;
  request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if(!error){
        siteData[path] = response.body;
         // call another request method
        count++;
        callback();
    }
   });
 },
 function (err) {
  // all the request calls are finished or an error occurred
  // manipulate data here 
  someFunction(siteData);
 }
);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above solution that promises are probably the way to go in this instance; however, you can use callbacks to achieve the same as well.

The lodash library offers convenient ways of tracking how many asynchronous calls have been completed.

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');
var path = require('path');

var paths = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var base = 'www.example.com';

var done = _.after(paths.length, completeAfterDone);

_.forEach(paths, function(part) {
    var url = path.join(base, part);
    asynchFunction(url, function() {
        done();
    });
});

function completeAfterDone() {
    console.log('Process Complete');
}

function asynchFunction(input, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(input);
        cb();
    }, Math.random() * 5000);
};
```

With this method the done function will keep track of how many of the requests have finished and will call the final callback once each url is loaded.